# SQL query return 0 when use count

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get query like this:

| Name | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| King | 3 |
| Queen | 1 |
| Single | 0 |

but when I use query

```
SELECT bedtype.bedTypeName ,COUNT(room_bed.bedTypeID) FROM room_bed
LEFT JOIN bedtype ON bedtype.bedTypeID = room_bed.bedTypeID
WHERE room_bed.roomID = 3
GROUP BY bedtype.bedTypeName
```

I got this:

| Name | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| King | 3 |
| Queen | 1 |

How Can I get above result ?

Table 1 : bedType

| ID | bedTypeName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | King |
| 2 | Queen |
| 3 | Single |

Table 2 : room_bed

| ID | bedTypeID | roomID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: have you tried using SUM?

Comment: yes. I tried but it can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. Firstly, you need to `LEFT JOIN` from `bedType` to `room_bed` to ensure that you get all bed types in the output result. Secondly, you cannot have a condition on the `LEFT JOIN`ed table in a `WHERE` clause; otherwise you convert that `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html)). Change your query to this:

```sql
SELECT b.bedTypeName AS Name, COUNT(r.id) AS `Count`
FROM bedType b
LEFT JOIN room_bed r ON b.ID = r.bedTypeID AND r.roomID = 3
GROUP BY b.bedTypeName
```

Output:

```
Name    Count
King    3
Queen   1
Single  0
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/myK3jQgujC5iNto9Msz8EE/0)

Answer (score 0):

try invert the tables  and use SUM checking for null

```
SELECT bedtype.bedTypeName , SUM(ifnull(room_bed.bedTypeID,0)) FROM bedtype
LEFT JOIN  room_bed  ON bedtype.bedTypeID = room_bed.bedTypeID
WHERE room_bed.roomID = 3
GROUP BY bedtype.bedTypeName
```

Comment: I getting old result.

Comment: Isn't it `isnull` instead of `ifnull`?

Comment: oh right my bad I read it too fast and thought about sql server!

Comment: @MMMMMMM   . update you question and add  a valid data sample (not only the expected result)  .. add  your tables scheda

Comment: I Updated. If something goes wrong I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these two and they will be fine

```
bedtype.bedTypeID = room_bed.bedTypeID
```

Comment: but SQL already like 
SELECT bedtype.bedTypeName ,COUNT(room_bed.bedTypeID) FROM room_bed
LEFT JOIN bedtype ON "bedtype.bedTypeID = room_bed.bedTypeID"
WHERE room_bed.roomID = 3
GROUP BY bedtype.bedTypeName
or not ?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it